# conda environment name changes upon using conda activate

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda, anaconda3

Output of `conda info --envs`:
[conda info --envs-o/p-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGStV.png)

I ran `conda activate tfgpu` (which is one of the existing environments, please refer to the above picture using the link).
Then I ran `conda info --envs`, the output of which is as follows:
[conda info --envs-o/p-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeif9.png)

As you can see, the name of the base environment is no longer visible and when I use `conda activate base`, the environment isn't changing anymore.

I found a workaround for this, which is as follows:

1. Run `conda activate <base_env_path>` from `tfgpu` environment
2. Run `conda activate base`
3. Finally , run `conda info --envs`. Output is: [conda info --envs-o/p-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGStV.png)

My question:
What should I do to make sure that `conda` doesn't change the name of the base environment, so that I wouldn't have to do steps 1-3 to resolve it?

**Please note that I cannot post inline images as my reputation is quite low.**

Comment: Please post text as text instead of images.  Images are less useful on SO for [a number of reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3282436).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted the second virtual environment tfgpu and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

While you are on tfgpu just do

```
conda deactivate
```

It will automatically deactivate your tfgpu environment and return to base environment. ( It does in my PC ).

In conda environment nesting is possible, afaik so when you are doing your mentioned steps 1-3 it **nests** your base environment over tfgpu instead of **switching**, this can cause issues.

> [ *Source* - [https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/a-series-of-path-problems-caused-by-nesting-conda-virtual-environments.html](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) ] 
> For details you may refer - https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html